# Kendo Grid first row just for searching

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a project which uses Telerik Kendo.
In the Kendo Grid, we need to make the first row editable so the user can type inside it to use it to search the data. Actually, the Kendo grid provides this functionality when you click on the header of the of the grid, but my requirement is to provide this functionality.

I searched the web for hours, without reaching any Result. 
I do not think I need to provide any code here, because I really do not know the way to go.

The project is ASP.NET MVC, and I am using Telerik MVC wrapper.

---

I used the row-filter feature which provided by Telerik, and it was good for me.
but I have small problem.

here it is what I used,

```
 function templateMethod (args) {
    args.element.kendoDropDownList({
          dataSource: args.dataSource,
          dataTextField: "color",
          dataValueField: "color",
          valuePrimitive: true
     });
 }
```

The previous example is from documentation of the Telerik from [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.filterable.cell#columnsfilterablecelltemplate)

> Keep in mind that the passed dataSource instance may still not be populated at the time the template function is called, if the Grid uses remote binding.

I am really using remote binding, and the data is NOT coming ,as the documentation state, the problem is that the documentation warned from this problem but it did not provide any solution for it.

How can I repupolate the kendoDropDownList again, after the data is coming from the remote server?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SomeClassName>()
              .BTGrid(GridName)
              .Resizable(e => e.Columns(true))
              .Filterable(e => e.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                   columns.Bound(x => x.VardiyaGrubu).Filterable(e => e.Cell(r => r.Template("templateMethod").ShowOperators(false).Operator("contains").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains) ));
              })
              .Groupable(config => config.Enabled(true))
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                  .Ajax()
                  .ServerOperation(true)
                  .Model(x => x.Id(r => r.RefKey))
                  .Events(ev => ev.RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
                  .Read(read => read.Action("CevrimZamaniRaporu", "Raporlar").Data(GridName + "_LoadData"))))
```

I tried to set `ServerOperation` to `true` and `false` in both cases it does not change.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the reason the header filtering functionality isn't adequate?

Comment: @Shai My boss did not want that, because it is not good UX. we want to increase the usability of the program.

Comment: You mean like this: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-row?

Comment: @CarstenFranke yes this is exactly what I want, I updated my question though

Comment: Please, post your grid definition as well. Did you set `ServerOperation(true)` in the datasource?

Comment: @CarstenFranke I posted the grid defintion

Comment: It´s not a good UX solution to use the fist row for search/filter. Users expect to have data on the fist row. Kendo Grid has the filter functionality build https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization If for some reason the functionality does not serve the propose templates can be used in the headers and it´s possible to implement input fields for searching/filtering data. Here is how https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.headertemplate